# Creating lparam for postmessage

Tags: c#, sendmessage, postmessage, param

I am having trouble with creating lparam for postmessage. I know that application gets such key:

```
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey: VK_CONTROL cRepeat:1 ScanCode: 1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0

WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey: VK_LEFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode: 4B fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0

WM_UP nVirtKey: VK_LEFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode: 4B fExtended:1 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1

WM_UP nVirtKey: VK_CONTROL cRepeat:1 ScanCode: 1D fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:1 fUp:1
```

could you tell me how I am supposed to create that lparam? I have read msdn, and I have made such lparam: `0x00011D00` and `0x00011D03` but they send such crap:

```
WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey: VK_CONTROL cRepeat:7424 ScanCode: 01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0

WM_KEYDOWN nVirtKey: VK_LEFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode: 00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0

WM_UP nVirtKey: VK_LEFT cRepeat:1 ScanCode: 00 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0

WM_UP nVirtKey: VK_CONTROL cRepeat:7427 ScanCode: 01 fExtended:0 fAltDown:0 fRepeat:0 fUp:0
```

Comment: why do you want to postmessage WM_KEYDOWN and WM_UP ?

Comment: The lower 16 bits are the repeat count.  So 0x1D00 = 7424.  You can't get this code to work, you must use SendInput() to control the state of modifier keys like Ctrl.

Comment: I've found Lparam using Spy++, but still that doesn't work, even though it is used same way as I would just click Ctrl+left arrow. How can I send multiplte key to background APP in C#? Somebody?